# Migration from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 for MSMQ

Tags: .net, msmq, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

We need to migrate our .net applications from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012. In that the main concern is about MSMQ.

Does anybody have any idea  how MSMQ  is affected ?

Answer (score 0):

Applications written for MSMQ 3.0 should, in general, work on later versions. There are a few areas to check:

1. Changes in the API
2. [Changes in message format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/06/29/the-message-format-has-changed-in-msmq-4-0-so-re-test-all-your-applications.aspx)
3. [Changes in security](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)